# Unable to install SVN in Eclipse Luna

Tags: eclipse, svn, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-luna

Unable to install SVN in Eclipse Luna for Ataccama DQC

When I am trying to add any path(like: Luna - http://download.eclipse.org/releases/luna ) in **Work with** text box under **Help --> Install new software** from the drop down, I am always getting a window to enter the user name and password and it shows:

"**Please provide login details for download.eclipse.org**"

It is always asking for credentials whenever I am trying to add any external paths/file. 
Environment details: Windows, VPN, client network
Please suggest if I can add the SVN plugin in this Eclipse Luna for Ataccama

Comment: Looks like a bug in DQC. Try to reinstall to be sure.